# Android, Eclipse: Right clicking on a source file results in Mac beachball!

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse SDK Version: 3.5.2 on OSX (Snow Leopard).

When I right click on a Java source file within the left-hand tree menu, the whole application freezes and I get the dreaded beachball for about a minute - once the beachball stops, the contextual menu is displayed.

The only plugins I have are the Android Dev Tools and Subclipse. How do I go about sorting this out, restarting my machine does not resolve the issue :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try altering your eclipse.ini for the minimum and maximum heap size?  I've often found that setting a large initial heap size makes Eclipse in general more responsive.

See the options [here](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try newer version of Eclipse. I am using latest stable (Indigo) and it works OK with similar setup.